# как найти медиану?

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть table `products` в нем есть столбец `price`

```
Id    Name      Price
1   Hard drive  240 
2   Memory      120 
3   SSD drive   70  
4   Flash drive 19  
5   Monitor     240 
6   DVD drive   39  
7   CD drive    23  
8   Printer     170
```

и нужно найти медиану для Price , как это сделать?

```
SELECT * from Products p
ORDER By p.Price
```

Comment: Как обычно, отсортировать, посчитать,взять середину.

Comment: как взять середину?

Comment: У тебя 8 записей. Половина - это 4. Вот 4-я запись при сортировке по price и есть медиана.

Comment: ну если там будет например 800202 записей

Comment: ??? не понял? ты на два делить не умеешь? ну так сервер умеет - да и делить всё равно ему, а не тебе...

Comment: и как мне взять четвертую запись? что делить на два?

Comment: Для нумерации записей - ROW_NUMBER. Для получения их количества - COUNT. Для деления пополам - `/`. Для выбора записи, у которой номер равен половине количества - `=`. Оконные функции - в CTE, выбор в основном запросе, деление или там, или там - без разницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1) Percentile_Disc (0.5)
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price)
           OVER()
FROM Products
```

Comment: PERCENTILE_DISC более правильно - Percentile_Cont интерполирует, и может вернуть значение, которого нет в таблице, при чётном количестве записей..

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Id, Name, Price,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY price) rn,
                     COUNT(price) OVER () cnt
              FROM Products )
SELECT Id, Name, Price
FOM cte 
WHERE rn = cnt / 2
```

Comment: что то тут второй select не работает SELECT Id, Name, Price

Comment: @SabaKoguashvili SELECT не может не работать. Он или возвращает результат, или сообщение об ошибке, третьего не дано.

Comment: @Akina согласен. Забыл что-то

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, Price ошибка => 1)Invalid column name 'Id'

Comment: @SabaKoguashvili Ну значит у вас нет `Id`  в таблице:)

Comment: есть в таблице  Id

Comment: @SabaKoguashvili а sql говорит, что нету:)

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL, PL/SQl есть встроенная функция медианы

```
select MEDIAN(Price)
  from products
```

В MS SQL Server

```
SELECT
(
 (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM
   (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Price FROM products ORDER BY Price) AS BottomHalf)
 +
 (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM
   (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Price FROM products ORDER BY Price DESC) AS TopHalf)
) / 2 AS Median
```

MS SQL Server 2012 (и более поздние версии) имеет функцию PERCENTILE_DISC, которая вычисляет определенный процентиль для отсортированных значений. [PERCENTILE_DISC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) (0.5) вычислит медиану -